# Conditions for Mellin inversion

Tags: cv.complex-variables, probability-distributions, integral-transforms

Under which conditions is the function

$$
g(s)=a^{c(s-1)}\Gamma(s),\qquad a>0,c\in \mathbb{R}
$$

the Mellin transform of a probability density function $f$? If $c=-1$, then $f$ is the exponential density. But what if $c\neq -1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The inverse Mellin transform  of this expression is particularly easy to do. Work it out, and you should be able to discern some answer to your question. Note that $(s-1)! = (\pi / sin(\pi s) ) (1/(-s)!)$ for determining the singularities for inversion.

Comment: @TomCopeland I tried to apply naively the Mellin inversion theorem (without taking into account the conditions on g) and the result, if I am not mistaken, should be $a^{-c}exp^{-a^{-c}x}$. This is a probability density function for every a>0 and real c. Am I right?

Comment: Do some numerical checks to bolster your confidence and / or catch mistakes. I use an old version of MathCad to numerically corroborate my symbolic results. It'll help you understand the forward and inverse Mellin transform better.

Comment: In the future, you might try asking questions at this level on Math StackExchange first.

Comment: @TomCopeland thank you for helping me. I am not so much into complex analysis. I tried asking on Math StackExchange, but got no answer.

Comment: You're welcome.